# Top in position relative is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-position

Why doesn't work top attribute for `<img>` , when the tag `<img>` is sibling to `<p>`, but if I delete tag `<p>`, this works.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus delectus accusantium nulla eveniet aperiam, quo odit qui voluptas. Illo vel sed ex dolores illum eum architecto a libero atque. Voluptatibus.</p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
```

Comment: Works perfectly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u64kmgu8/)

Comment: @Tushar in your fiddle I see the behaviour described by Mariadicar. Delete the p with firebug or the like and the img suddenly goes further down...

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see? I don't understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/9bxwxfe2/

Use a container `div` set to `position: relative;` and then add `position: absolute;` to the img.

Answer (score 1):

```
CSS:

html,body{
        height: 100%;
}

img{
        position: relative;
        top: 40%;
        float:left;
}
```

Use float:left; in the img class. This will solve the problem and  image will be displayed in expected position(40% from the top of the screen).

Answer (score 1):

**When the value is provided as a percentage, it is relative to the height of the containing block.**

But `img` has no containing block. You can add `position: absolute;` to the img.

CSS:

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May this help you...
My suggestion is to use px instead of %. It works fine.

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

img{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vy301c07/

Answer (score -1):

Added float:left for p tag

New css,

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

img{
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
}
p {
    float:left
}
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reshmar/qqo03uf7/1/)